# Implementation of abstract class as type

Tags: typescript, typing

I want to define a type for a property of my class:

```
abstract class CoolStuff {
    protected abstract service: any;
}
```

This service is an abstract too:

```
abstract class BaseService<T,K> {
     // Code
}
```

So i'd expect this:

```
abstract class CoolStuff {
    protected abstract service: BaseService
}
```

But then the compiler expects me to define `T` and `K`. But these are already defined in the implemented Service:

```
class ActualService extends BaseService<Collection, Model>{
    // Code
}
```

So what i want to do is something along the lines of:

```
abstract class CoolStuff {
    protected abstract service: instanceof BaseService;
}
```

But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to make `CoolStuff` generic as well, and then you can specify the actual types in the derived classes of `CoolStuff`

```
abstract class CoolStuff<T, K> {
    protected abstract service: BaseService<T, K>;
}

class CoolStuffWithActualService extends CoolStuff<Collection, Model> {
    protected service: ActualService
}
```

You might also get away with specifying `any` as a type parameter in `CoolStuff`, but this results in weaker typing in the base class as it can pass anything to `BaseService` which may be an issue.

```
abstract class CoolStuff {
    protected abstract service: BaseService<any, any>;
}

class CoolStuffWithActualService extends CoolStuff {
    protected service: ActualService
}
```

**Edit**

A third option would be to have the service type itself as a type parameter to `CoolStuff` and constrain it to be of type `BaseService<any, any>`

```
abstract class CoolStuff<TService extends BaseService<any, any>> {
    protected abstract service: TService
}

class CoolStuffWithActualService extends CoolStuff<ActualService> {
    protected service!: ActualService
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to tell to check the ActualService class?

Comment: @Funonly Not sure what you mean .. the `CoolStuff` will have a property of type  `BaseService<T, K>` not `ActualService`, but the derived class will have a preoprty of whatever type they specify ..

Comment: @Funonly added third option as well, maybe this one better suits your needs

Comment: @Titan Yes this somewhat approaches what i had i  n mind. I guess my problem is with me having to define `T` and `K` in ActualService and in `CoolStuffWithActualService`. I excpected only having to define it in `ActualService` and since in `CoolStuffWithActualService` `ActualService` is referenced it would be resovled.